# Django forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField not saving anything

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have had so many problems with `forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField` and `widget = forms.SelectMultiple` I'm hoping someone can put me out of my misery.

I'm using the `JQuery Chosen` multiple select box (similar to Select2) to render out the `interest` field in the `ProfileUpdateForm` on the font-end.[image: example]

At first the `request.POST` was not executing at all, the submit button wasn't clickable and I got the error `An invalid form control with name='interest' is not focusable` which I have now patched by adding

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileUpdateForm, self,).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['interest'].required = False
```

to my `ProfileUpdateForm`.

Although I can now click the submit button and see

`[2019/02/18 08:26:53] HTTP POST /profile 302`

and all other form information updates ...nothing happens to the `forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField` `interest` field.

If you select an `interest` then press `submit`, the `SelectMultiple` field is empty on page refresh and nothing is stored / saved. I've checked the admin and nothing has updated in that section.

What is the best way to proceed to diagnose the problem?

forms.py

```
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    interest = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Interest.objects.all(),
        widget = forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={
        'name': "interest",
        'data-placeholder': "Choose your interests",
        'class': 'chosen-select',
        'multiple tabindex': '4',
    }))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(ProfileUpdateForm, self,).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.fields['interest'].required = False

    class Meta:
         model = Profile
         fields = ['interest', 'age', 'bio']
```

views.py

```
def profile_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                   request.FILES,
                                   instance=request.user.profile)
        if p_form.is_valid():
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'p_form': p_form,
    }

    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

profile.html

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <!-- edit Profile model info -->
     {{ p_form|crispy }}
     <button type="submit" value="submit">Update Profile</button>
</form>

<script>
        $(".chosen-select").chosen();
        $('button').click(function() {
          $(".chosen-select").val('').trigger("chosen:updated");
        });
</script>
```

models.py

```
class Interest(models.Model):
    interest_name    = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['interest_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.interest_name

class Profile(models.Model):
    user            = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    interest        = models.ManyToManyField(Interest)
    bio             = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Comment: Can you show your model?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Hi Daniel, I have updated to include models.py. Best.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I initially thought `ManyToMany` may be causing a problem but I think it is appropriate as one user can have many interests and one interest can also be shared by many users.

Comment: Well the problem appears to be that you're not sending any data at all on submit. What is the point of that `$(".chosen-select").val('').trigger("chosen:updated");` line? What happens if you remove it?

Comment: The rest of the data is submitting because when I go into admin and check, the data has been updated..well all but interests. Removing that line has not changed anything.

Comment: My apologies, I must have taken out an extra character, but when I take out that line it works. Thank you. If you add it as an answer I will mark it correct.